# How do you pass a string via props then use that as a value in the component tag in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I have a String name tag and I passed it from 'Main' component to 'Details' component  via props and want to use that tag string to use in the render function of Details like

Tried this in the render function of 'Details', not working

```
render() {
    const Tagname = this.props.navigation.getParam('component', 'Component Does not exist')
    return (
      <Container>
        <Tagname/>
      </Container>
    )
  }
```

The value of `const Tagname` is `Basic` (console logged) and I have a component created and imported correctly named `Basic`

Here is the Main :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    <View>
      <Text
        style={styles.texts}
        onPress={()=> {
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
            component: 'Basic'
          })
        }}
      >
        {elem}
      </Text>
    </View>
  }
}
```

The router :

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import Details from './Details'
import Main from './Main'

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Main,
  },
  Details: {
    screen: Details,
  },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

The Details :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import Basic from './Basic.js'

export default class Details extends Component {
  render() {
    const Tagname = this.props.navigation.getParam('component', 'Component Does not exist')
    return (
      <View>
        <Tagname/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

The Basic :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Basic extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello world</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide all relevant code, such as your main component where you render `<Details />` and pass the props

Comment: Have you tried console logging the tagName to see what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to map string with corresponding component, you could use an object, like that:

```
import Basic from './Basic';

const components = {
  Basic,
};
```

And in your render function:

```
render() {
    const Tagname = this.props.navigation.getParam('component', 'Component Does not exist');
    const Component = components[Tagname];
    return (
      <Container>
        <Component/>
      </Container>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. Is it because it was a string and needed to be an object?

Comment: React want a component inside a jsx tag. So when you use a string instead, it don't work. React can't retrieve your component with a simple string.